# CSS float moves content down

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

**Test Cases**

I have 3 simple text cases as following:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #000;">
    <a href="#" style="">Text1</a>
    <a href="#" style="">Text2</a>
    <a href="#" style="float: right">Text3</a>
</div>
```

Examining this in IE8, Firefox (23), as expected the `Text3` link is aligned to right properly. As soon as I add border to links, `Text3` drops down by one pixel (size of border)

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #000;">
    <a href="#" style="border: 1px solid #000;" href="#" >Text1</a>
    <a href="#" style="border: 1px solid #000;">Text2</a>
    <a href="#" style="border: 1px solid #000; float: right" href="#">Text3</a>
</div>
```

Now if I try adding padding to links, `Text3` drops down much further (12 pixels padding+ 1 pixel border)

```
<div style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px; border: 1px solid #000;">
    <a href="#" style="padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px; border: 1px solid #000;">Text1</a>
    <a href="#" style="padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px; border: 1px solid #000;">Text2</a>
    <a href="#" style="padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px; border: 1px solid #000; float: right">Text3</a>
</div>
```

**Problem**
It seems when floating an element, padding and border size are ignored and the actual position of elements are used.
I have a multi theme web page. user can choose any of themes from `jQuery UI Theme roller`
In each of these themes the style that I am using for items, have a different padding size (and font size) which makes it impossible to hardcode specific value in CSS to make them stay in same line.

**Questions**
Is this behavior avoidable (Am I doing it wrong)?
Is there a workaround to make these links stay in the same line (preferably only css)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the other `a` elements to `display: inline-block` they will all behave in the same way. E.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

a {display: inline-block; padding: 12px;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div style="border: 1px solid #000;">
    <a href="#" style="">Text1</a>
    <a href="#" style="">Text2</a>
    <a href="#" style="float: right">Text3</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```